# Cabal and HPC and Errors when Running Tests with Code Coverage

Tags: haskell, cabal

I use Cabal to run my tests.

Here is how it is configured in the `.cabal` file:

```
test-suite test
    type:           exitcode-stdio-1.0
    main-is:        Test.hs
    build-depends:  base >= 4.7 && < 4.8, containers >=0.5 && <0.6, ghc, test-framework >=0.8 && <0.9, QuickCheck >=2.7 && <2.8, HUnit >=1.2 && <1.3, test-framework-hunit, test-framework-quickcheck2
    default-language:    Haskell2010
    ghc-options:    -Wall -fhpc
```

When I run the test the first time, everything is OK.

However, if I change the tests and run them again, I get the following error:

```
Hpc failure: module mismatch with .tix/.mix file hash number
(perhaps remove test.tix file?)
```

So, I need to manually remove the `.tix` file.

Is there a way to get rid of this problem?

By the way, is there a way to have this `.tix` file generated in the `dist` directory instead of at the root directory?

How can I configure my Cabal file to work nicely with HPC (i.e. having the generated HTML files in the `dist` directory)?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using `--enable-coverage`? If you don't, then you probably should. If you do, then you don't need `-fhpc`.

Comment: No, I don't use it. I've just tried to use it but I get the following error: `cabal: unrecognized 'test' option --enable-coverage` when running `cabal test --enable-coverage`. The Cabal User Guide does not seem to indicate how to use it. Can you explain me how to use it, please? Thanks.

Comment: You should enable the flag when configuring: `cabal configure --enable-converage`. Then run tests as usual.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what is was looking for. If you put that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: What's the effective difference between --enable-coverage and -fhpc? I was using both. Is that a problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make `cabal` generate code coverage report, you can enable that when configuring your package:

```
cabal configure --enable-coverage
```

Then run tests as usual:

```
cabal test
```

Note that you may need `--enable-library-coverage` with older `cabal`. Also IIRC `hpc` integration in cabal was broken for `ghc-7.6`.

Comment: How should I run my application to get the *.tix file in the dist directory? I tried `cabal run` but the *.tix file is created in the current directory.

Comment: @antoyo try `HPCTIXFILE` environment variable. Try `cabal test -v3` to see how `cabal` uses it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using GHC 7.8.3 and Cabal 1.22.0.0

You can set the file path of the .tix files in a couple of ways.

1. Set the HPCTIXDIR environment variable. The tix file will be created in the provided directory.  The name will be formatted as -.tix
   If the directory doesn't exist it will be created.
2. Set the HPCTIXFILE environment variable.  The tix file will be created with the file name you provided in the current working directory.  You can specify a file path.  But, the directory won't be created.